Updating PostgreSQL using subqueries and joins
I have the following tables in my PostgreSQL database:

buildings

 id |           name           | abbreviation 
----+--------------------------+--------------
 31 | 4705 Fifth Avenue - Dept | 4705FIFTH-D
 28 | 4705 Fifth Avenue        | 4705FIFTH
...


buildings_networks

 id  | buildings_id | networks_id 
-----+--------------+-------------
 143 |           31 |         159
 144 |           31 |         160
 147 |           28 |         153
 148 |           28 |         154
 149 |           28 |         155
 159 |           31 |         179
...


networks

 id  |          name          | display_name 
-----+------------------------+--------------------
 179 | 4705FIFTH-D -- fmcs    | fmcs (staff)
 153 | 4705FIFTH -- onboard   | onboard (residents)
 154 | 4705FIFTH -- private   | private (residents)
 155 | 4705FIFTH -- public    | public (residents)
 159 | 4705FIFTH-D -- onboard | onboard (staff)
 160 | 4705FIFTH-D -- private | private (staff
...

I'm trying to update the buildings_networks table so that ALL of the networks (including those that have a -D in their name) are associated with comparable building without the - Dept in its name.
Using the example above, the buildings_networks table should ideally look like this:
 id  | buildings_id | networks_id 
-----+--------------+-------------
 143 |           28 |         159
 144 |           28 |         160
 147 |           28 |         153
 148 |           28 |         154
 149 |           28 |         155
 159 |           28 |         179
...

I realize that this could be done row-by-row in the example, but there are many additional buildings and networks than those that I provide in this example.  So a single query would save a lot of time.
The other buildings are varied, but there are always two of each building.  The first subset is one with a - Dept at the end of its name, like 4705 Fifth Avenue - Dept.  A -Dept building always has an abbreviation that ends with -D, like 4705FIFTH-D.  The second subset of building has a name and abbreviation without the - Dept and -D, 4705 Fifth Avenue and 4705FIFTH, respectively.
In addition, there are always two kinds of network names.  One subset is those with a -D at the end of the first part of the name, like 4705FIFTH-D -- onboard.  The other subset is without the -D, like 4705FIFTH -- onboard.
I have tried this:
UPDATE buildings_networks bn
SET buildings_id = subquery2.building_id
FROM (
  SELECT b2.id AS building_id, b2.name, b2.abbreviation, bn2.networks_id
  FROM buildings b2
  INNER JOIN buildings_networks bn2
  ON bn2.buildings_id = b2.id
  WHERE b2.abbreviation NOT LIKE '%-D'
) AS subquery2
INNER JOIN buildings b
ON b.id = subquery2.building_id
WHERE replace(b.abbreviation, '-D', '') LIKE subquery2.abbreviation
OR b.abbreviation LIKE subquery2.abbreviation;

That seems close, but it sets ALL of the buildings_id values to a single value (e.g., 400+ records in addition to those shown in this example) rather than per building.
This query produces the same (undesired) result:
UPDATE buildings_networks
SET buildings_id = (
  SELECT b2.id 
  FROM buildings b2 
  WHERE b2.abbreviation = REPLACE(b.abbreviation, '-D', '')
)
FROM buildings_networks bn
INNER JOIN buildings b 
ON b.id = bn.buildings_id
WHERE b.abbreviation LIKE '%-D';

What am I getting wrong?

You're using buildings_networks twice.

Try this, the idea was to have only the right ids then join on the correct abbreviation
update buildings_networks  
set buildings_id = right_ids.id
from buildings 
join (
    select id, abbreviation 
      from buildings
     where abbreviation not like '%-D'
) right_ids on buildings.abbreviation like concat(right_ids.abbreviation, '%')
where buildings.id = buildings_networks.buildings_id


This worked, thank you so much!  I appreciate you taking a look.
